# tgetent/ncurses errors while compiling ircII on Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, ncurses

I'm running ircii-20190117 configure with usual options like --enable-ipv6,  and what I see (many times met on other web pages) error:

```
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no  
checking for tgetent in -ltinfo... no  
checking for tgetent in -ltermlib... no  
checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no  
checking for tgetent in -lxtermcap... no  
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no  
configure: WARNING: i can not find tgetent.  you might need to help me
```

As I said - I visited many web pages where users gave their advises to install various ncurses libs. Now I show what I have already installed and got no problem solved:

```
build-essential/stable,now 12.6 amd64 [installed]  
libncurses5/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 amd64 [installed]  
libncurses-dev/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 amd64 [installed]  
libncurses5-dev/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 amd64 [installed]  
libncurses6/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 amd64 [installed,automatic]  
libtinfo-dev/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 amd64 [installed]  
ncurses-base/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 all [installed]  
ncurses-term/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 all [installed]
```

Can someone provide help how to tell ircII to use those libs like inserting needed paths into Makefile:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

-- or - use them in ./configure script run ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting help from Guru it was found problem with "-g" option, so this is what needed to make compiler do the stuff:

> echo ac_cv_prog_cc_g=no > config.cache
> ./configure --prefix=$HOME --config-cache